google OpenID, get only an id_token
EDIT: Just as I feared, this looks like to be due to the nature of the client. If I create a “Web application” client I do not have an issue with the id_token response type.
Can someone confirm or infirm this? And explain why this restriction is in place?

I’m trying to retrieve an ID token from the OpenID login provided by google on their services.
I actually succeeded in doing so, but I’m required to set the response_type to code id_token.
As it so happens, I do not need nor want the code! The response type I want is id_token, and it is listed as being supported in the public configuration.
As can be seen in the request below, my client ID is a mobile client ID (iOS).
Here’s the request I’m sending, which works (with added newlines for readability):
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
   client_id=...&
   response_type=code%20id_token&
   scope=openid%20profile%20email&
   redirect_uri=reversed.client.id:/oauth2callback&
   nonce=...&
   state=...

If I replace response_type’s value with id_token, I get the following error:

What part of my request is incorrect for google to refuse this response code?

FLOW VARIATIONS
If you use the following option you operate similarly to the implicit flow and receive a front-channel response. There is no proof of the client's identity:
response_type=id_token

If you use the following option you use the hybrid flow which is considered more mainstream than the implicit flow, so is more likelt to be supported. Yet it still has potential issues.
The hybrid flow returns an ID token in the browser response which may end up in server logs or the browser history. The ID token may reveal personal data (eg if it contains a name or email). In higher security setups you are also meant to use encrypted ID tokens in the JWE format to prevent this.
response_type=code id_token

If you use the following option you use the code flow and get all tokens in the most secure way with the simplest code. You use PKCE and a client credential and receive all tokens in a back channel request that proves the client identity. It is recommended in order to comply with recommendations like FAPI 2.0.
response_type=code

Providers like Google tend to align with best practice recommendations so may not support older or lower security options.
HOW AUTHORIZATION SERVERS WORK
If you use an authorization server (AS), your client runs a code flow to the AS. You can configure the AS to use a Sign In with Google option, or some other identity provider (IDP).
When doing so, the AS runs a second code flow to the IDP. It always uses response_type=code and receives an authorization code. The AS then exchanges the code for a full set of IDP tokens using a client credential, then validates the IDP's ID token. By default it ignores other IDP tokens.
RESOLVING YOUR PROBLEM
If you are connecting to Google directly I would follow the same pattern of running a code flow. One issue you may run into is that some IDPs may require a client secret, which you cannot store safely in a public client. To work around that, I would route the token request via a backend component, eg a small utility API.
ORIGINAL QUESTION
I realise this does not answer your point about how you have found that Google allows response_type=id_token for a web client but not for a mobile client. That feels like a question that only Google could answer. Yet using the most standard flow feels like your preferred resolution.

That I understood more or less, thanks for the clarification.
The question remains: why code id_token accepts sending the ID token but the id_token response code is rejected? And also, why would a web client allow id_token alone, but not a mobile client? Both are using the same flow (and receive the info in the fragment); one is not more secure than the other AFAIK.

I agree that doesn't feel logical  Someone from Google may need to provide an answer - it might even be a bug. You will have fewer incompatibilities when using the most standard flow though

Out of interest, how do you trigger the mobile login. Do you use a Chrome Custom Tab? I know Google are quite strict on blocking logins from webviews ...

It’s on iOS, I use an ASWebAuthenticationSession which is specifically designed for retrieving authentication elements from an authorization URL.

Cool - that's all good then. I added some points to my answer, though I'm, not sure if it gives you everything you wanted.

Everything’s clear, I knew most of this already, I was really curious as to why the id_token alone was not supported for mobile clients. Your answer is excellent but I cannot accept it as it does not answer my original question. As you said I’m afraid only google knows the answer :-) Thanks anyway!
